Is it possible to customize invitation emails within a single user pool in AWS Cognito?
I'm building multiple separate apps but would like users to be able to log into one app and be automatically logged into all of them.
My plan was to use a single Cognito user pool to accomplish this. Each app would have its own signup UI and then the user would get an email to confirm ownership of the email with a link back into the original app to sign in.
Problem is I see that email customization is at the user pool level, not the app client level, so I'm not able to customize the emails with that degree of granularity.
There's 2 solutions I'm floating right now and would love to know if there's a simpler/better/less hacky one:

Create a generic endpoint in our service making the Cognito API calls that redirects the user to the app that they originally came from. Put that URL into the generic email template and tack on the username as a query param, which is available from the email template.
Just switch to using OTP verification emails (no need to customize the email at all).

